# Does #temp table share data to multiple users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using #temp in my store procedure. Does it share data with multiple users like ##temp?
There is some issues in my store procedure so i need to confirm it. please help if you can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you answered your own question. As far as i know #temp would not and ##temp would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table that starts with a single hash, like `#tblname`, is a [local temporary table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). It is only visible to your current connection. In most cases, you're better off using the newer table variable.  Example of a table variable:

```
declare @tbl table (id int, col1 varchar(50))
```

The two hashes in `##tblname` make it a global temporary table. It is visible to all connections.

Comment: You are incorrect about global temp tables. See your own link.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: Yeah, copy/paste gone wrong :) already updated.

Comment: We cant't define the table, Actually we don't know the structure.